# I often see something like this v3io:// or /v3io/blah/blah, what are the difference

Tags: nuclio, mlrun

I often see something like this `v3io://` or `/v3io/some-directory, what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

The file at `v3io://bigdata/my_file` and `/v3io/bigdata/my_file` is exactly the same, but is accessed differently.

A path with `v3io://` is accessed via the Iguazio V3IO protocol. This is generally more performant, but is not compatible with all libraries

A path with `/v3io` is accessed via a mounted filesystem. This is not as performant as the V3IO protocol, but is compatible with more libraries

I recommend using `v3io://` where possible and falling back on `/v3io` when it is not

Comment: Is the 'v3io://test/file' the same as 'v3io:///test/file' (I added one '/')?

Comment: Is it possible to see more information about v3io protocol?